# Compute percentage change between two number in variables

Tags: php, math, percentage

I have an array stored into a $data variable that looks like this:

```
["data"]=>
  array(413) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#254 (7) {
      ["Date"]=>
      string(10) "2016-09-06"
      ["Open"]=>
      string(6) "771.00"
      ["Close"]=>
      string(6) "782.00"
    }
  }
```

I take the Open value like this:

```
$open = $data->data[0]->Open;
//meaning $open outputs 771.00
```

And the Close value like this:

```
$low = $data->data[0]->Close;
//and $close outputs 782.00
```

I make a difference between them:

```
$diff= $open - $close;
//outputs -11
```

Then I have to display the percentage change from `$open` to `$close`, which in this case is `-0.3%` or something like that. But these numbers variate daily, because every day a new record is stored in this array, so tomorrow `$open` ca be higher than `$close`.
How can I compute the percentage change between them?

Comment: This is basic arithmetic not a coding problem

Comment: http://www.mathematics-monster.com/lessons/percentages_how_to_express_one_number_as_a_percentage_of_another_number.html

Comment: Agree, sorry for the php tag, I didn't know if I should've put it, sadly I didn't take math kindly in university

Comment: Nor me, but I can Google with the best of them

Comment: Wtf ....I completely forgot that is the way to solve it.....I feel embarrassed :( but thanks for this 4th grader lesson :)), I am sorry for this question

Comment: No sweat, we all do it from time to time. I think its called brain fade